# Resize div's height when the page i zoomed

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming

I have a div and i want that It has always 80% of body's height.I have thought a function that catch body's height when site is loading and calculate 80% of It giving the result at div's height.The problem is that when the user do the zoom of the page div's height doesn't resize.How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

use this style for your div :

```
height: 80vw;
```

Comment: When i zoom in or out a browser's page,viewport's height and width change?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the height to be 80% in css given the div is direct child of `body`

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 80%;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>yo</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

alternatively use `height: 80vh;` if your body is 100% viewport height.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 80vh;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>yo</div>
  </body>
</html>
```